# Go Programming - How to pass two structs in ExecuteTemplate

Tags: struct, go

I am a golang beginner and I am developing a web application to understand better the golang concepts.

I have a html page which I want to show some informations about User and about a Product.

So, now I am passing only the Product struct to the Product html template, like this:

```
ExecuteTemplate(w, "product", Product)
```

But I have some informations that are not in this struct. That are in the User struct.

I would have to do something like this:

```
ExecuteTemplate(w, "product", Product, User)
```

I mean that I have to pass both structs to the same template. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

Invoke the template as

```
if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "product", 
     struct{Product, User interface{}}{Product, User}); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

You can access product and user inside the template as:

```
{{.Product}}
{{.User}}
```